# Creating my first trigger in Postgresql with syntax error near "LANGUAGE"

Tags: postgresql, function, database-trigger

I need to learn more about postgres but I am trying to write a function that links to a trigger in my postgres db. Normally the functions I write work fine, however, this particular function keeps returning errors around the syntax at the end of my output.

I have a fixtures table with a column called 'Result'. I want to read the scores from the fixture e.g. Wolves 0:0 Ipswich, and trigger into Result 'Draw'.

The query I am writing is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sppullscoretrigger()
RETURNS trigger

SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
  payload text;
BEGIN
    SELECT NEW.Home_Side_Score, NEW.Away_Side_Score FROM Fixtures;
        IF    NEW.Home_Side_Score is NULL or NEW.Away_Side_Score is NULL THEN NEW.Result = 'TBC';
        IF NEW.Home_Side_Score = NEW.Away_Side_Score THEN NEW.Result = 'Draw';
        IF NEW.Home_Side_Score > NEW.Away_Side_Score THEN NEW.Result = 'Home_Win';
        IF NEW.Home_Side_Score < NEW.Away_Side_Score THEN NEW.Result = 'Away_Win';
        ELSE NEW.Result = 'Error';
        END IF;


    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER trgscore
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON Fixtures
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sppullscoretrigger();
```

I have only written basic functions before but I am really struggling with getting this trigger to work.

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the trigger function (and before the `create trigger`). Also: `SELECT NEW.Home_Side_Score, NEW.Away_Side_Score FROM Fixtures;` will select ***all*** rows from the table `fixtures` but with constant values for each row. You do not need that select at all. In a row level trigger you can just access the `new` and `old` records

Comment: Thank you. I have put the missing semi-colon in and that resolved the issue as well was the ELSIF issue identified by Joachim.

Comment: I have just tried using this trigger when I insert data and it tells me "Error: record 'New' has no field 'home_side_score' CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT New.Home_Side_Score is NULL or New.Away_Sido_Score is NULL"...." Any ideas? I thought the New attribute would hold the data I am importing so there would be a field home_side_score etc.

Comment: Yes it will. But to find the cause of the error you need to [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table. But it's probably better  to ask a new question for that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using `IF` when you mean `ELSIF`. This version compiles;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sppullscoretrigger()
RETURNS trigger

SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$

DECLARE
  payload text;
BEGIN
    SELECT NEW.Home_Side_Score, NEW.Away_Side_Score FROM Fixtures;
        IF    NEW.Home_Side_Score is NULL or NEW.Away_Side_Score is NULL THEN NEW.Result = 'TBC';
        ELSIF NEW.Home_Side_Score = NEW.Away_Side_Score THEN NEW.Result = 'Draw';
        ELSIF NEW.Home_Side_Score > NEW.Away_Side_Score THEN NEW.Result = 'Home_Win';
        ELSIF NEW.Home_Side_Score < NEW.Away_Side_Score THEN NEW.Result = 'Away_Win';
        ELSE NEW.Result = 'Error';
        END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

[A quick SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/120a8).

Comment: I have just tried using this trigger when I insert data and it tells me "Error: record 'New' has no field 'home_side_score' CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT New.Home_Side_Score is NULL or New.Away_Sido_Score is NULL"...." Any ideas? I thought the New attribute would hold the data I am importing so there would be a field home_side_score etc.